# Fitting Corsair H60 into NZXT m59

Tags: cooling, computer-building

I'm building a desktop for the first time with the NZXT m59 case and I'm trying to install a Corsair H60 liquid cooler.

It appears to be already set up and everything so all I need to do is attach it to the case, CPU, and motherboard.  It doesn't seem to comply with my case, though; the side panel will not close with it put in the direction and position that the instructions show.

I've searched and found that other people faced and fixed the same problem by moving around parts, but with different cases.  I really have no idea where I could move this cooler.

I guess I'm mainly looking for anybody with this specific case or enough knowledge to tell me something that would apply to any case with this cooler.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you simply cannot, and most of the people who have installed that specific combination needed to cut parts out of the case. According to [this random forum post](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic161803.html) you will need to remove the top fan closest to the back and put the cooler there, and it may be necessary to trim the side panels, apparently [removing some beading along there for it to fit](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bluebob951/5501729442/in/photostream)

Comment: Yeah, I was considering just cutting that area off, but how exactly would I do that without melting or destroying the rest of the case?

Comment: by the looks of things, he used a grinder in a rotary tool like a dremel. VERY careful use of a grinding wheel and fibre glass cutting wheel should do the trick. In a perfect world, you'd probably want to mill it off, but not everyone has that sort of tools lying around.

Answer (score 2):

The radiator on the H60, as you found out, is about 1 inch taller than the 120mm fan that it comes with. That means that you have to have a least 1/2 inch of clearance above and below the fan opening for it to fit.

In my case, the 120mm fan opening is right up against the power supply. In your case, it appears that the fan opening is right up against the top of the case.

I had to measure and drill new mounting holes for the H60 mounting screws to shift the placement of the radiator down sufficiently to fit in the case. Note: This was with the hoses on the radiator toward the bottom of the case.

If you remove the rear fan from your case and the radiator can fit between the top panel and the expansion card slots, then you can drill new holes in the case and use those to mount the fan and radiator.

Comment: It doesn't fit there the way they suggest with the radiator touching the case and the fan pulling through the radiator, but I think it will fit if I make the fan push instead.  There are already holes on the top of the case that it will fit to.  Do you know what effect this would have on the cooling power of it?

Comment: The only way to mount it is with the fan mounted against the case and the radiator on the inside since the screws tighten into the holes in the radiator casing.